# Unable to verify if Nvidia OpenCL is installed

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I followed the steps mentioned here: http://orbigo.net/2012/07/installing-nvidia-opencl-cuda-sdk-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Everything worked fine till the step mentioned below:

> Now everything is ready to start compiling. Just grab a coffee, and wait for your workstation to finish:
>
> ```
> victor@proliant:~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK$ make
> ```
>
> It will take several minutes depending on how fast your computer is. But afterwards you will have everything ready to try and test. The binaries are generated in `OpenCL/bin/linux/release` and `C/bin/linux/release`.

I am unable to find the GPU Computing SDK on the Nvidia website. Can someone please tell me how I could verify that I can run opencl code on my machine. It would be great if you could tell me how to compile nvidia opencl code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial is outdated. The SDK and the examples are now part of the CUDA toolkit.

You should follow these [instructions from NVIDIA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) instead. They will guide you through installation up to compiling and running the examples.

Comment: I could not find the gpu*.run file. Can you please post the link. I went to this page https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads, but all i could find there was the cuda toolkit. Please help!

Comment: Thanks. I have the cuda toolkit installed. I am looking at the sample code available in /usr/local/cuda/samples/, but there are no opencl kernels here. They are all CUDA kernels.